Qemu - how to create qcow2 image as a disk clone of a windows drive selectively? How to handle boot partition?
I have a 2TB drive where I have 100MB boot partition, 300GB C: drive, rest 1.7TB is a partition for games.
I want to clone that, but I don't want to clone games - only the 300GB + 100MB is what I care about. I can find tons of guides how to clone whole drive to .qcow2, or a single partition to .qcow2. I want to ignore 1.7TB partition which contains only games, and do a whole drive clone, with image that would be 300.1GB of size (C: drive + boot).
So my question is - how to clone a drive selectively, only boot partition + c: drive, to a .qcow2 image - is this possible?

I would try one of:

From Windows use disk2vhd.exe to create a .vhdx containing the selected partitions, then fix the virtual disk's partition table to match, and (if needed) trim the virtual disk's "size" to match its contents without the empty space after. Qemu-img can be used to convert from VHDX to Qcow2.

From Linux create a blank Qcow2 image of the needed size (make it at least ~1024 sectors or ~1 MB larger than the 'end' sector of the last partition you need, so that it'd have space for the trailing secondary GPT). Attach the image using qemu-nbd. Use sfdisk to clone the partition table over, then use ntfsclone or partclone to copy each partition one by one.



Thanks! the disk2vhd looks interesting!
